# Is it possible call wasm from evm smart contract on substrate chain?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, evm, pallet-contracts

Is it technically possible to call wasm contract from evm contract inside substrate chain that include pallet-contracts and pallet-evm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is be possible through Astar Network xvm_pallet, interaction between WASAM and EVM Contract. You can go through [this](https://medium.com/astar-network/building-a-multichain-network-with-xvm-4e905e93cd7e) article and there is also video for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86M5w8UjHjU).

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely technically possible.

1. It's possible to extend pallet-contracts with so-called [chain extensions](https://ink.substrate.io/macros-attributes/chain-extension/). One could write such an extension that allows calling pallet-evm.
2. The typical way of extending EVM is via adding new "precompiles". pallet-evm allows adding new precompiles by modifying the [precompiles configuration](https://docs.rs/pallet-evm/latest/pallet_evm/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.Precompiles).